# SQL Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

If someone can help me with this script I would greatly appreciate it.

So I am basically trying to use a Foreign Key to reference a table with multiple Primary Keys and I keep getting an Error. When I run the create table script for personal trainer, I get this error:

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
>   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Schedule' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK__Personal_Trainer__38996AB5'.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 3
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Here is the CREATE TABLE script for both tables. I am trying to use a foreign key in personal trainer to reference the table in schedule. `FitnessWebApp` is the name of the database.

```
use FitnessWebApp

create table Schedule
(
    day char(20),
    time char(20),
    name char(30),
    gymName char(30)
    primary key (name, gymName, day, time)
);

use FitnessWebApp

create table Personal_Trainer
(
    name char(30),
    gymName char(30)
    primary key(name, gymName),
    foreign key (name, gymName) REFERENCES Schedule(name, gymName)
);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql-server%5D+There+are+no+primary+or+candidate+keys+in+the+referenced+table

Comment: There's no such thing as a "a table with multiple Primary Keys" - you have a table with a *composite* primary key. There can be only one primary key. It looks to me like you're trying to create the FK the wrong way around (shouldn't the schedule be referencing a trainer rather than vice versa?)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 create table Personal_Trainer (
   id int(10) not null,
   trainerName char(30), 
   primary key (id));

 create table gym (
   id int(10) not null,
   gymName char(30),
   primary key (id));

 create table Schedule (
   id int (10) not null,
   trainerId int(10), 
   gymId int(10),
   gymDay Date, 
   gymTime Datetime, 
   primary key (id),
   foreign key (trainerId) REFERENCES Personal_Trainer (id),
   foreign key (gymId) REFERENCES gym (id));
```